# Symfony2 FPNTagBundle

Tags: php, symfony

I implemented the **FPNTagBundle** in Symfony2. 
I can now associate tags with an Entity. When I'm adding something with a form to a table, it works very well. Tags are created in the database.

But I didn't get how I can load them with my edit form.
I created a new input field for the tags in my FormType, but this one is of course empty.

Here is my edit method where I want to load the tags already associate with the entity called **Activity**.

```
public function editAction(Activity $activity)
    {
        $editForm   = $this->createEditForm($activity);
        $deleteForm = $this->createDeleteForm($activity->getId());

        $tagManager = $this->get('fpn_tag.tag_manager');
        $tagManager->loadTagging($activity);

        return $this->render('ComiteoASCBundle:Activity/Activity:edit.html.twig', [
            'activity'    => $activity,
            'edit_form'   => $editForm->createView(),
            'delete_form' => $deleteForm->createView(),
        ]);
    }
```

And the **createEditForm** method:

```
private function createEditForm(Activity $activity)
    {
        $allowEditCategory = ($activity->getProducts()->count() === 0) ? true : false;

        $form = $this->createForm(new ActivityType($allowEditCategory), $activity, array(
            'action' => $this->generateUrl('activity_activity_update', array('activity' => $activity->getId())),
            'method' => 'PUT',
        ));

        $form->add('submit', 'submit'));

        return $form;
    }
```

You guys have any idea how to load the tags in the input field?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it. It is actually very simple:

You just have to iterate in twig with a for loop.

```
{%  set tags = '' %}

{% for tag in activity.tags %}
   {%  set tags = tags ~ tag ~ ', '  %}
{% endfor %}

{{ form_row(edit_form.tags , {'attr': {'value': tags} } ) }}
```

Of course, don't forget to load your tags in your controller before:

```
$tagManager = $this->get('fpn_tag.tag_manager');
$tagManager->loadTagging($activity);
```

I'm now trying to remove the last comma in my twig template with **trim** but it doesn't seem to work!

```
{{ form_row(edit_form.tags , {'attr': {'value': tags|trim(",")} }  ) }}
```

Any Idea?